# keep letter spacing intact while changing the SVG width

Tags: html, css, svg

Here is an SVG with a text inside:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {

  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}
```

```html
 <div style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

<svg height="42.655499999999996" width="257.8288" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <defs>

       <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
       </linearGradient>

       <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
          <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
          <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
          </feGaussianBlur>
          <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
       </filter>

    </defs>

    <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

    <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
       <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
          <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
       </g>
 
       <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
          <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
       </text> 
       
    </g>
</svg>
<div>
```

The problem is when I decrease the SVG width (only width and not the height) the letter spacing of the text inside decreases too and this is not what we want. we want to have the text intact.

Here is the result if we set the width to 157 pixels:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {

  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}
```

```html
 <div style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.6555px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(139px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

<svg height="42.655499999999996" width="157.8288" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

    <defs>

       <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
       </linearGradient>

       <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
          <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
          <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
          </feGaussianBlur>
          <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
       </filter>

    </defs>

    <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

    <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
       <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
          <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
       </g>
 
       <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
          <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
       </text> 
       
    </g>
</svg>
<div>
```

I have tried to put text tag outside of the SVG tag or changing the letter spacing using CSS but those weren't good ideas.

NOTE: I need to only change the width of the SVG... in other words, I don't want to preserve Aspect Ratio

Comment: If you don't want the SVG to scale, remove the viewBox attribute.

Comment: remove the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` The text will look smaller but you can change the viewBox value to keep the text size